# How to change a program and all its subroutines executable?

Tags: chmod, executable

for running a program, I need to change its install file to a executable file. I can do that, but my problem is that program calls some subroutines and those need to be executable too. Is there any way to change the mode of those files at once. I do not want to make all files executable, just subroutines.
Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to find which subroutine in which file & than apply chmod to all that files.

Comment: Actually, I did that. There were a lot of files. Anyway, it's good to know if there is a way.

Comment: How can the files be identified? Are there any names or other features?

Answer (score 0):

Like for script files command

```
find -name "*.sh" -type f -exec chmod +rx {} +
```

This command find all script files & give full permission.

I hope this help you

Comment: -1 for `chmod 777`. Also, `chmod` doesn't read from standard input.

Comment: Sorry , now I think it works

Comment: And for files without the extension `sh`?